# How to convert this Observer into a lambda

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to convert this into a lambda even after googling.

```
mEventActivityViewModel.getEventInfo()
        .observe(this, new Observer<List<EventInfoDao.EventInfo>>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<EventInfoDao.EventInfo> eventInfo) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Seems that what you want is `....observe(this, eventInfo -> {})`, given you current empty implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mEventActivityViewModel.getEventInfo().observe(this, eventInfo -> {
  //your code inside onChanged
});
```